# How do I implement a high-performance piecewise linear transfer function in Eigen?

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I need some help optimizing an Eigen-based implementation of a piecewise linear transfer function (output value is equal to the input but capped to a range, in this case [-0.5,0.5]). Below is the function that I profiled:

```
typedef float SignalT;
typdedef Eigen::Array<SignalT, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Signal2D;
void ActivateSum(unsigned char const idx, Signal2D::ColXpr& outputSum)
{
    switch (idx)
    {
    case 0U:
        //Threshold
        outputSum = (outputSum >= (SignalT) 0.0).cast<SignalT>();
        break;
    case 1U:
        //Piecewise linear
        outputSum = outputSum.unaryExpr([](SignalT const elem)
        {
            if (elem >(SignalT) 0.5)
                return (SignalT) 0.5;
            else if (elem < (SignalT)-0.5)
                return (SignalT)-0.5;
            else
                return elem;
        }
        );
        break;
    case 2U:
        //Fast Sigmoid
        outputSum *= ((SignalT) 1.0 + outputSum.abs()).inverse();
        break;
    default:
        assert(0);
        throw;
    }
}
```

My entire program spends the following fraction of samples in each of the switch cases:

```
Threshold: 3.3%
Piecewise Linear: 18%
Fast Sigmoid: < 0.1%
```

The fast sigmoid is rarely used but the piecewise linear case should occur as often as the threshold case (although I don't know how to measure this using Visual Studio). So it seems to me like I'm spending quite a lot of time in that Piecewise linear unary expression and was wondering if there was an alternative method to achieve the functionality in Eigen, perhaps by using some in-built methods to juice up the speed. It's a very simple transfer function so it really should be computationally quite cheap - my guess is that the cost has more to do with poor optimisation due to my custom lambda than anything else.

Thoughts?

EDIT: So far I've come up with this thanks to Leeor's answer:

```
case 1U:
    //Piecewise linear
    outputSum = outputSum.max((SignalT)-0.5).min((SignalT)0.5);
    break;
```

Comment: You want saturating arithmetic. "Piecewise linear transfer function" is way too general, and suggests 1. that you have an arbitrary number of lines of arbitrary slope, not just one line of slope = 1, and 2. that you're in the frequency domain which you're not.

Comment: @Potatoswatter well I don't know what it's called, but you can look at the code and see what I'm after (I thought it was called piecewise linear transfer function). Regarding the switch/case; it has absolutely diddly effect on performance whether you use if/else, a lookup table or switch/case. The reason being that outputSum has a length of > 20,000, so the guts of the operation is inside those `case` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FPU maximum and minimum instructions, if your existing code doesn't already compile that way already.

```
    outputSum = outputSum.unaryExpr( [] (SignalT elem)
    {
        return std::fmax( -0.5f, std::fmin( 0.5f, elem ) );
    }
```

Eigen might already have such operations built-in but a glance at the docs didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Yup, it does! `outputSum = outputSum.max((SignalT)-0.5).min((SignalT)0.5);`

Comment: @ausairman Cool, did this improve performance? Be sure to profile both ways; I think Eigen is smart enough to interleave the chained operations but you can't be too sure.

Comment: Yup, substantially, that operation now takes the same amount of CPU-time as the threshold function.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly branch prediction, your if conditions create a complicated data-dependent control flow, with multiple return sites possibly making it hard to optimize.

Perhaps ternary operators like this would eliminate the branches:

```
        return (elem>0? 1 : -1) * (std::min(std::abs(elem),0.5));
```

(make sure you use a lib that supports abs on floats, i think cmath should be fine).

See if you compiler emits less-branchy code that way by doing this with conditional moves.

Comment: The ternary operator generates branches the same as an `if`. The control flow graph that the compiler's optimizer sees will be exactly the same.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Not exactly, the original code returns out of the function from multiple locations within the if code. I'd be very surprised if a compiler can swap this with conditional operations.